# only in windows10, Java Keyevent doesn't work.. in Windows7 and 8 it works well.. I don't know why

Tags: java, swing, awt, keylistener

1. I am making KeyEvent Test program, but it doesn't work in Windows10.
2. this program works well in Windows7 and 8 version.. I don't know why..
3. KeyBoard Problem..? or others..?

   ```
   class KeyFrame extends JFrame{

          public KeyFrame(){
           KeyTest t = new KeyTest();
           setContentPane(t);
           this.setSize(700, 700);

           setSize(300,300);
           setVisible(true);
           t.requestFocus();
       }
   }

   public class KeyTest extends JPanel{

       JLabel la = new JLabel("Input");

       public KeyTest(){
           add(la);
           this.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
               public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){
                   String data = e.getKeyText(e.getKeyCode());
                   la.setText(data + "Pressed");

                   if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_F1){
                       setBackground(Color.GREEN);
                   }
                   else if(e.getKeyChar() == '%'){
                       setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
                   }
               }
           });
       }

       public static void main(String[] ar){
           new KeyFrame();
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Ah, `KeyListener`, destroying developers lives since for ever.  `KeyListener` is fickle at the best of times and I think you've just been lucky it's worked (consistently) on the other platforms. I'd suggest you try using the [Key Bindings API instead](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you are adding KeyListener for JLabel.

**Note:Some components aren't focusable like JLabel.**

You can try that one.

Make sure the component's isFocusable method returns true. This state allows the component to receive the focus. For example, you can enable keyboard focus for a JLabel component by calling the setFocusable(true) method on the label.